# Should I use an alternative from CPAN to replace Frontier::RPC2?

Tags: perl, xml-rpc, cpan

I have been using Frontier::RPC2 for my XML-RPC server, with Frontier::Client on the client side... but have noticed these modules have not been maintained recently.

Discussion at the bottom of [this page](https://rt.cpan.org/Public/Bug/Display.html?id=36220) mentions some fresher alternatives on CPAN.  What would the pros and cons of these be?  I honesty don't have an immediate need to switch, but there are some annoying "uninitialized" variable warnings produced by Frontier::RPC2 which I'd love to rid myself of... they are clogging up and making it difficult to find more salient warnings in my webserver log.

Any recommendations for upgrading my web service?

Answer (score 3):

You could just fix [Frontier::RPC2](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Frontier-RPC2) so it's warnings clean. That's kinda the point of free and open source software. :)

If you are already using this module and it works fine except for the warnings, why switch? Just fix the warnings. Submit a patch to [RT](https://rt.cpan.org/) for the module. If the maintainer has disappeared, the admins at modules@perl.org can help you get your patch applied.

Comment: I do realize that.  But while I was at it, I got to wondering if there might be other advantages to switching to something more current.